# How pass array to php page with a html button

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm trying to pass an array to a php page

this is my code:

this my code:

```
<li>{$dataResources|@print_r}</li>

 <a href="../../Page.php?f={$dataResource|@json_encode|rawurlencode}">
     <input type="button" value="Create Invoice" style="float: right;">
 </a> 

    {/if}
```

In Page.php:

```
$data = json_decode($_GET['d'], true);
```

but It not works, is null!

This is the array format:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [owner_name] => Sale [start_date] => 2018-01-17 14:00:00 [end_date] => 2018-01-17 17:00:00 [resource_name] =>  Plus [resource_id] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [owner_name] =>  Plus [start_date] => 2018-01-17 17:00:00 [end_date] => 2018-01-17 18:00:00 [resource_name] =>  Plus [resource_id] => 5 ) ) 1
```

Comment: Can you store the array in a session and just access it on the 2nd page?

Comment: you've got a few things bad in your code, your _a href_ should get changed to the following to be more correct `../../Page.php?d={$dataResource|@json_encode|rawurlencode}`

Comment: Yes sorry this was a typo. Thanks